# Iterate over only files stored in git

Tags: bash, git

I want to run a couple search and replace `sed` commands on my git repository, but I don't want to modify automatically generated files. Is there an easy way to only iterate over the files that are checked into git.

Some of these filenames may contain spaces.

Comment: Can you clone your repo elsewhere so it doesn't contain any of the `.gitignore` stuff, do your `sed`, `commit`, `push`, and then `fetch`/`pull` back in your original working directory?

Comment: @JNevill I think the right answer is using `fd` with `--exec`

Comment: Nice. I haven't run into [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) before. That's a nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all files under version control with `git ls-files` (run from repository root); to account for exotic filenames, use the `-z` option to separate with null bytes:

```
while read -d '' -r fname; do
    echo "$fname" # or sed, or whatever you want
done < <(git ls-files -z)
```